# Java add a non-editable tJTextField in one line

Tags: java, jtextfield

We can add an editable JTextField to a panel in one line like this `panel.add(new JTextField(text));` in Java. Is there a standard way to set it non-editable using something like `panel.add(new JTextField(text).setEditable(false));` without writing our own method?

Comment: You can do it in one line, but you shouldn't: `panel.add(new JTextField(text){{setEditable(false);}});`. Just do it on multiple lines or write a method to do it. Your code will be easier to read that way.

Comment: Move it to answer please, so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: I wonder, why minus? Is this question too broad? Off-topic?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because (I'm pretty sure) it's not possible to call a function on the constructor, as it doesn't actually return anything. The only way I can think of doing it on one line would be to use semi-colons so like this: `JTextField field = new JTextField(text); panel.add(field.setEditable(false));` Note that, although it looks like one line the compiler thinks it's actually two because of the semi-colon

Comment: I have 10 JTextFields that I want to attach to a panel. I think, a `//comment` followed by a copy-paste is more readable than 20-30 lines of code.

Comment: @ resueman Your method worked, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Stepan I'd really suggest creating a method which does all the initialization you want on the text field. If you later decide you want something additional done to it, then it will be much easier to change then.

Comment: @Stepan - create a nonEditableJTextFieldFactory which has create method which does those two lines and returnes the text field

Comment: Extend a JTextField and setup a new constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do it that way, but you still shouldn't.

```
panel.add(new JTextField(text){{setEditable(false);}});
```

This creates an anonymous class, which sets it as not editable in the initialization block.

Doing it that way is considered bad practice though. You should just split it into multiple lines, or write a method to do it. The code will be more maintainable and easier to read that way.

Comment: I realize this is a write only code, but I will explain that it is equivalent to a three liner in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Create a proper factory method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    NonEditableTextFieldFactory nonEditableTextFieldFactory = new NonEditableTextFieldFactory();

    panel.add(nonEditableTextFieldFactory.createNonEditable());
    panel.add(nonEditableTextFieldFactory.createNonEditable());
    panel.add(nonEditableTextFieldFactory.createNonEditable());
}

static class NonEditableTextFieldFactory
{
    public JTextField createNonEditable()
    {
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        jTextField.setEditable(false);
        return jTextField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Learning a factory method is on my todo list.